# How to add a custom button inside list.blade.php in Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I'm working with the  Backpack crud 3.2. in Laravel 5.4.

---

What I need is to add a new custom button inside the list.blade.php near to the Edit and Delete button. And to link another view to the new button.[image: please take a look at the screenshot]

I had gone through the lines inside the list.blade.php. 
I know there are blade files for each  buttons,fields and views. But even I couldn't find how these Edit and Delete button were added?

---

Could anyone help with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In CURD controller, you can create button here :

`public function setup()
  {
    ..............
    // ------ CRUD BUTTONS
    // possible positions: 'beginning' and 'end'; defaults to 'beginning' 
    for the 'line' stack, 'end' for the others;
    // $this->crud->addButton($stack, $name, $type, $content, $position); 
    // add a button; possible types are: view, model_function 
    ..............
   }`

You can see more : https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-buttons